# How to add a bottom solid border in a responsive toggled navigation bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <style>
    a {
      color: #e02846;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a:hover {
      color: wheat;
    }
    
    .nav-div {
      background-color: #1A1A40;
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="nav-div">
      <div class="boot-nav" style="padding: 10px;">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="images/youtube-128.png" alt="Logo" width="35" height="29" class="d-inline-block align-text-top"> SafTube
          </a>

          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto" style="text-align: right; border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;">
              <li>
                <a href="./index.html">
                  <h3>home</h3>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="index.html">
                  <h3>Contact</h3>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="index.html">
                  <h3>About</h3>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

  </header>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I want to create a responsive navigation bar where by when viewed in a smaller device it generates a toggler of an unordered list items with a bottom border to separate each item. also When viewed in a larger device, the bottom border should NOT appear in the list items

`


SafTube

```
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto" style="text-align: right; border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;">
                    <li><a href="./index.html"><h3>home</h3></a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html"><h3>Contact</h3></a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html"><h3>About</h3></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </nav>`
```

i tried adding the **border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa** style in my unordered list and this is what i get
[large device view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKgu4.png)

an unwanted bottom border appears and also when toggled on a smaller device
[Small device view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JF3gN.png)
only the last item gets a bottom boarder

Comment: When asking a question, you need to provide all code that is relevant to your question. The images you sent indicate styling that is not Bootstrap 5's default. Therefore, you have custom CSS. You need to send this CSS. Also, please fix your code snippet.

Comment: the code snippet has been updated

Answer (score 0):

The best way i found to solve this was using was to use media query

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <style>
    a {
      color: #e02846;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a:hover {
      color: wheat;
    }
    
    .nav-div {
      background-color: #1A1A40;
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
      li {
        border-bottom: 2px solid black;
        padding-top: 3px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="nav-div">
      <div class="boot-nav" style="padding: 10px;">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="images/youtube-128.png" alt="Logo" width="35" height="29" class="d-inline-block align-text-top"> SafTube
          </a>

          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto" style="text-align: right;">
              <li>
                <a href="./index.html">
                  <h3>home</h3>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="index.html">
                  <h3>Contact</h3>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="index.html">
                  <h3>About</h3>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

  </header>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```